# Get button from a fragment in Android

Tags: android

I was working with and slider tab, insaid the main view I have 2 tabs and insaid them, I have a XML to set the UI. Everything is perfect, I get my slide tabs and I can run the app. The problem is when I try to get a button from my fragments. I was reading about LayoutInflater, but I couldn´t solved.

Please, I think I don´t undestand very well how the fragment works and I would like a little of help about this.

This is my main activity (onCreate):

```
 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    facebookLogin = new FacebookLogin(getApplicationContext());
    setContentView(R.layout.register_tabs);

    toolBar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolBar);

    adapter =  new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(),Titles,Numboftabs);

    pager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    pager.setAdapter(adapter);

    tabs = (SlidingTabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
    tabs.setDistributeEvenly(true);

    tabs.setCustomTabColorizer(new SlidingTabLayout.TabColorizer() {
        @Override
        public int getIndicatorColor(int position) {
            return getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimary);
        }
    });

    tabs.setViewPager(pager);
}
```

I my main XML:

```
<LinearLayout
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
 android:orientation="vertical"
 tools:context=".MainActivity">

 <include
     android:id="@+id/toolbar"
     layout="@layout/toolbar"
     />

 <com.cheescake.clasi.all.SlidingTabLayout
     android:id="@+id/tabs"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:elevation="2dp"/>

  <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/pager"

    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    />

 </LinearLayout>
```

And the XML and class where I have my button:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="6">

        <Space
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="3" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1">

            <Space
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="3" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                android:text="Inicia sesión para comprar y vender los mejores productos  "
                android:id="@+id/textView"
                android:gravity="center" />

            <EditText
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:inputType="textPersonName"
                android:hint="@string/user_name"
                android:ems="10"
                android:id="@+id/editText"
                android:layout_weight="2"
                android:gravity="bottom" />

            <EditText
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:inputType="textPassword"
                android:hint="@string/user_pass"
                android:ems="10"
                android:id="@+id/editText2"
                android:layout_weight="2"
                android:gravity="bottom" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                android:textSize="10dp"
                android:text="¿has olvidado tu contraseña?"
                android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
                android:id="@+id/text_loggin"
                android:layout_weight="1.3"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:gravity="right" />

            <Space
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1" />

            <com.google.android.gms.common.SignInButton
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="New Button"
                android:id="@+id/button"
                android:layout_weight="1" />


            <com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/login_button"
                android:layout_weight="1" />

            <Space
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="3" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <Space
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="3" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.8"
        android:background="@color/bottomBackground">


        <Space
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="5" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:text="@string/finish"
            android:id="@+id/txtNextButton"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center" />
      </LinearLayout>
  </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

The class of the fragment:

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton;

public class RegisterTabLogin extends Fragment {

private LoginButton loginButton;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v =inflater.inflate(R.layout.register_tab_login,container,false);
    return v;
  }
}
```

As I say, I just want to get a View from the fragment and work with it in the Main Activity, I was reading about LayoutInflater but I could´t solved, Also I read some questions here, ([Using button from a fragment in main activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25546614/using-button-from-a-fragment-in-main-activity)) but I couldn´t solved.

Any help will be gratefull, a link o something.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried this?

```
public class RegisterTabLogin extends Fragment {

private LoginButton loginButton;
private LoginCallback mCallback;

@Override 
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v =inflater.inflate(R.layout.register_tab_login,container,false);
    loginButton = (LoginButton) v.findViewById(R.id.login_button);
    showData.setOnClickListener(onClickListener);
    return v;
}

@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    super.onAttach(activity);
    try {
        mCallback = (LoginCallback) activity;
    } catch (ClassCastException e) {
        throw new ClassCastException(
                "Activity must implement LoginCallback.");
    }
}

private final OnClickListener onClickListener = new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (mCallback != null) {
            mCallback.onLogin();
        }
    }

};
public static interface LoginCallback{
    void onLogin();
}
```

}

then on MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements
        RegisterTabLogin.LoginCallback {

        @Override 
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    facebookLogin = new FacebookLogin(getApplicationContext());
    setContentView(R.layout.register_tabs);

    toolBar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolBar); 

    adapter =  new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(),Titles,Numboftabs); 

    pager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    pager.setAdapter(adapter); 

    tabs = (SlidingTabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
    tabs.setDistributeEvenly(true); 

    tabs.setCustomTabColorizer(new SlidingTabLayout.TabColorizer() { 
        @Override 
        public int getIndicatorColor(int position) {
            return getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimary);
        } 
    }); 

    tabs.setViewPager(pager); 
} 


        @Override
        public void onLogin() {
            //DO SOMETHING
        }
}
```

Comment: Yes, I tried, but I had a problem, I can work fine with the button, but I get problems becouse is a FacebookButton and I need the callbackManager, I think, is more ease get the button in the main activity (but I dont sure).

Comment: have you tried to implement also an interface to sent back to mainactivity any action?

Comment: Mmmm no, I was trying to pass the MainActivity to my fragments, but I dont know if is the best way... also, I didn´t work with interface yet. I going to look for tutorials about this.

Answer (score 0):

In your Main Activity, access this view in the `OnStart()` method like this:

```
@Override
protected void onStart() {

    Button yourButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.yourButton);

    super.onStart();
}
```

EDIT:

Your fragment should be present in your Main Activity.
You can add `RegisterTabLogin` in a certain `containerView` present in your Main Activity layout in the `OnCreate()` method like this:

```
RegisterTabLogin registerTabLogin= new RegisterTabLogin();
getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.a_certain_layout, registerTabLogin).commit();
```

Comment: I get a null in my button.

Comment: Because your fragment `RegisterTabFragment` isn't present in your Main Activity yet

Comment: And how I can get it? I cant create a object of this class in my MainActivity.

Comment: And you should add this object to a certain layout present in your Main Activity. Check my edit

Comment: I tried this, but I cant get the fragment id because I have not the fragment into a XML, I added programmatically, I tried to get the id with "getId()" but the method gave a number...

Comment: The id is not for a fragment. It is for a container in your Main Activity (a LinearLayout for example) where your fragment will be added to it

Comment: Check this [example](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aSRJynmOvFo&list=PLonJJ3BVjZW4lMlpHgL7UNQSGMERcDzHo&index=7) if you're still not familiar yet with this method